Differentiating Entropy with respect to Convolution Parameters
First, some formula reminders for the sake of completion:

$H(X) = -\sum_{i} p(x_i) \log p(x_i)$ is the entropy of a sequence $x_i$, where $p(x)$ is the discrete probability of x.

A discrete convolution is defined as $(f * g)(n) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} f(m) g(n - m)$


I'm trying to find an expanded and computable expression for: $\frac{\partial H(X * A)}{\partial a_i}$ where $A = [a_1,a_2,...a_i,...,a_k]$
I'm doing this to ultimately get the gradient of the entropy of this convolution with respect to the parameters of A, which I'll then use to code a gradient descent algorithm. I have a hunch this could likely be solved by using the convolution theorem in some way:
$\mathcal{F}(f * g) = \mathcal{F}(f) \cdot \mathcal{F}(g)$
I'm having issues understanding how to apply the partial derivative over the discrete probability functions (Probability Mass Functions). Is it linear?
Thank you!
EDIT: Taking a few ideas from @Stefan Lafon 's answer, I believe I have made progress.
$\frac{\partial P((X * A)[n])}{\partial a_i} = \frac{\partial P((X * A)[n])}{\partial ((X * A)[n])} \cdot \frac{\partial (X * A)[n]}{\partial a_i}$
And, as Stefan pointed out,
$\frac{\partial (X * A)[n]}{\partial a_i} = x_{n-i}$
Thus, after more chain rule and simplification
$\frac{\partial H(X * A)}{\partial a_i} = \frac{[\frac{\partial P((X * A)[n])}{\partial ((X * A)[n])} \cdot x_{n-i}]^2}{p((X * A)[n]) \cdot ln(2)}$
However, I still don't know how to properly compute the discrete $\frac{\partial P((X * A)[n])}{\partial ((X * A)[n])}$, or if my continuity-assuming steps so far were valid (in partial differentiation with the chain rule etc).
As an additional clarification, $X = [x_1,x_2,...,x_j,...x_N]$
Any additional help would be greatly appreciated!

Using the definitions works :)
For simplicity of exposition, I will use $p_i$ in lieu of $p(x_i)$. $X$ is the random variable on $\mathbb Z$ with distribution $\{p_n\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$.
We are also considering another sequence $A=\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$. You seem to be assuming that $a_j=0$ if $j\leq 0$ or $j>k$, but this is not necessary.
The convolution of $X$ and $A$ is given by
$$(X*A) (n) = \sum_{m\in\mathbb Z}a_m p_{n-m} $$
To be able to consider the entropy of $X*A$, it will be necessary to assume that for all $n$, $a_n\geq 0$ (or else $(X*A)(n)$ might be negative, and the log might not be defined).
Anyway, fixing $n$ and taking the partial derivative w.r.t. $a_i$ gives: $$\frac{\partial\left[(X*A)(n)\right]}{\partial a_i} = p_{n-i}\tag{1}$$
The definition of entropy of $X*A$ is: $$H(X*A) = -\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} (X*A)(n)\log(X*A)(n)$$
Taking the partial derivative and applying $(1)$:
$$\begin{split}
\frac{\partial H(X*A)}{\partial a_i}&=-\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \left[p_{n-i}\log(X*A)(n)+(X*A)(n)\frac{p_{n-i}}{(A*X)(n)}\right]\\
&=-\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \left[p_{n-i}\log(X*A)(n)+p_{n-i}\right]
\end{split}$$
Using the fact that $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}p_{n-i}=1$$
$$\boxed{\frac{\partial H(X*A)}{\partial a_i}=-1 - \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} p_{n-i}\log(X*A)(n)}$$
And if you consider the random variable $\widetilde X$ whose distribution is the mirror image of $X$, that is $\{p_{-n}\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$, then a more compact way to write the result is:
$$\boxed{\frac{\partial H(X*A)}{\partial a_i}= -1 - (\widetilde X * \log (X*A))(i)}$$

Thanks for this! But I'm not quite grasping some things. Wouldn't $(X \ast A)(n) = \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} x_m a_{n-m}$? Perhaps the misunderstanding is that X is somehow a probability, when it is in fact an "array" like A. $X = [x_1,x_2,...]$. If that is the case, I apologize for the misunderstanding, since my notation might have been at fault. $p((X \ast A)(n))$ denotes the probability of finding the element $(X \ast A)(n)$ in $(X \ast A)$. Am I simply misinterpreting your answer?

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\h{\cdot}
\def\s{\star}
\def\cv{\circledast}
\def\BR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\red#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\red{\LR{#1}}}
$Let $(\s,\cv)$ denote cross-correlation and convolution products (respectively) and for typing convenience, define the variables
$$\eqalign{
p &= p(x) \\
b &= a\cv p &\qiq db = da\cv p \\
B &= \Diag b &\qiq b=B\h\o,\qq B^{-1}\h b = \o \\
q &= \log(b)+\o \\
}$$
Also define the symbol $(\h)$ for the dot product
and $(\o)$ for the all-ones vector.
Write the entropy using the above notation,
then calculate the differential and thence the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
H &= -b\cdot\log(b) \\
\\
dH &= -\log(b)\h db  \;-\; b\h\BR{d\log(b)} \\
 &= -\log(b)\h db \;-\; b\h\LR{B^{-1}\h db} \\
 &= -\BR{\log(b)+\o}\h \red{db} \\
 &= -q\h \CLR{p\cv da} \\
 &= -\LR{q\s p}\h da \\
\\
\grad Ha &= -\LR{q\s p} \\ &= -\BR{\log(a\cv p)+\o}\s p \\
}$$

Thank you for the insight! However, how does the discrete probability function fit into this? Wouldn't it falsify the entropy formula if we ignore it?
